# Is grading unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-modules

It must be a very basic question, but I just can't figure out...

Let $P$ be a graded $A$-module ($A$ is a commutative associative with unity). Can $P$ have two *different* direct decompositions, that is

$P=\bigoplus_{d\geq 0}M_d=\bigoplus_{l\geq 0}N_l$ with $M_d\ne N_l$?

Comment: Polynomials in two variables could be graded by degree of one or of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Your question is not really clear anyway. I'll try to clarify your point of view.

Let's start with a small example: with $A=\mathbb{R}$ and $P=\mathbb{R}[X]$:

$$M_d=\mathbb{R}\cdot X^d,\qquad N_d=\mathbb{R}\cdot(X-1)^d.$$
We do have:
$$P=\bigoplus_{m\in\mathbb{N}}M_m=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}N_n,$$
yet
$$\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N}^*,\ M_m\neq N_n.$$
(note that $M_0=N_0$, but that could be artificially fixed). So the answer is yes.

Now let's have a look at the (pedantic) proper definitions of graded rings and modules (using $\mathbb{N}$ as the set of indices for the sake of simplicity):

> A *graded (Abelian) ring* is a pair $\bigl(A,(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigr)$ where $A$ is a (Abelian) ring and $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of subgroups of $A$, such that $A=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$ and for all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, $A_mA_n\subset A_{m+n}$.
>
> If $\bigl(A,(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigr)$ is a graded (Abelian) ring, a *graded $\bigl(A,(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigr)$-module* is a pair $\bigl(P,(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigr)$ where $P$ is an $A$-module and $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of subgroups of $P$, such that $P=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}P_n$ and for all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, $A_mP_n\subset P_{m+n}$.

As it's usually tedious to always specify both the ring/module and the sequence explicitly, and since we're (most of the time) only working with one sequence, we usually only mention the ring/module or the sequence, as this definition has some kind of redundancy. And this may bring some kind of confusion.

Now, formally, with the example I gave above: I'm talking about the graded ring

$$\bigl(\mathbb{R},(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigr)$$
where
$$A_0=\mathbb{R},\quad\forall n\geq1,\ A_n=\{0\},$$
and there I defined *two distinct* graded $\bigl(\mathbb{R},(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigr)$-modules:

$$\bigl(P,(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigr)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\bigl(P,(N_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigr).$$
Even though $P$ is the same in both cases, as graded $\bigl(\mathbb{R},(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigr)$-modules they are distinct.
So the answer is no.

Comment: @user26857 you're right, as graded modules they are not equal... but the question isn't clear: does OP want two distinct direct sum decompositions that are compatible with the grading of the ring for the same underlying module (answer is yes), or does OP want two distinct graded modules that have the same underlying module, yet distinct underlying sequence (in which case answer is trivially no, by the very definition). The purpose of my post is to clarify the formal (and pedantic) definition so that OP can have a clearer point of view. I hope this goal will be achieved!